# Which is better option JSON? or CSV? (for large data (~1 GB) from remote server to (frontend of) web application

Tags: json, csv

I am trying to fetch large tabular data from a remote url which send data in binary format. To read this data I am using a **C** program that runs (inbuilt) with server. The **C** program fetches fetches data in binary format from various sources, convert into readable form and send it to frontend.

The I have two option:

1. I convert the data into CSV format which is lighter or
2. I convert the data into JSON format which is little heavier but easy to interpret by frontend web application

I want to to operations like sorting and grouping of data in frontend. So can you suggest me which is better option to use in this scenario.

Updates:
1 -> frontend will just receive the data and may do sorting or grouping

Comment: do you need to send back and forth all the datas ?pagination will be done on client side or server side ? staging on a database is a viable option ? even if is binary transfer GBs are GBs

Comment: frontend will only receive the data do some operations like sorting or grouping and forget it.

Comment: isn't either answer equally valid?. Consider re-phrasing your question.

Comment: just thinking about using a frontend for sorting and grouping gives me nasal demons. Better have a mid-tier back-end solution and a thin front-end publishing API.

Comment: yes it should be done by database but somehow requirement is like this and I don't want to send same data again and again (in sorted form for each column user click)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must send all the data to the front end, you could use a json array to wrap each row. This minimises the amount of extra data you are adding e.g.

```
data:{
     columns:["A","B","C"],
     rows:[  [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]   ]
}
```

However, I would try to avoid sending all the data to the fronend application if possible. It should be possible to show pages of data by fetching the required data on demand using ajax calls. The server can do the heavy work of sorting, grouping etc. Consider storing the data in a database.

Comment: what is the difference between sending the data in JSON format as you suggested and sending data in csv format with top row as headings of the column

Comment: You won't have to parse the csv in the client.

Comment: Thanks, I was confused as size of both will remain almost same then how much difference it can make in parsing